# Why do low-rep users post new answers to already answered & accepted questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, new-users, popularity

I think the title says it all. Many times I've seen low-rep users (usually 1 rep) that don't have any previous activity on SO post useless and/or plagiarized answers to already answered questions (with a high up-vote).

For example, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398871/update-all-objects-in-a-collection-using-linq), which has 100+ upvotes and an accepted answer with almost 200 upvotes earlier today got [a new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25426174/) by a 1-rep user and the answer is a copy of the accepted answer.

I'm just curious as to why this happens. Is it related to some badge?

Comment: It's impossible to establish intent. There's certainly no badge that intentionally rewards this behavior.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - what about [Necromancer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/17/necromancer)?

Comment: Because they can

Comment: @ChrisF I think that badge might have been what I was thinking of.

Comment: @jpw - however, posting an useless or identical answer isn't going to get them that badge.

Comment: Don't make assumptions about intent -- It could be that people just think they have something to add and are trying to be helpful. I posted an answer to an old question with an accepted answer *and* a relatively high voted (different) answer when I had almost no rep. The reason was none of the answers addressed the subject thoroughly and I felt I had something to add (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386040/whats-wrong-with-nullable-columns-in-composite-primary-keys/16124563#16124563).

Comment: @zxq9 My question concerned the act of reposting already posted answers, not contributing new original ones which is a totally different and positive case. I'm certainly not questioning the latter case; at the time I posted the question I was curious about the copycat answers, and I did get good answers.

Comment: @jpw Perhaps I just don't often scroll down far enough on really old/high vote questions to notice the scourge of copycat posts. In any case, this may partly be why certain high rep Q/A sets get closed when they are considered fully baked (which also seems to risk letting obsolete answers linger... but everything is a tradeoff when dealing with feral netizens).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is obvious why it happens—they want to post an answer. The site is intentionally rigged to drive people towards the answer box.

And yes, posting an answer entails the possibility of getting upvotes, which are desirable because they [unlock privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges). Namely the [ability to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), something that you don't get until 50 reputation and a privilege that all new users seem to desire immensely.

It is only natural that they pick questions they are able to answer. Either because the question is easy and something they already know about, or because they can steal the answers from someone else. Frankly, though, I have no idea where these people come from that think outright plagiarism is justifiable. Or even that they will get away with it!

However, I will quibble a little bit with what I see as an undertone in your question. Some could take your question (at least the title and first few sentences) as implying that no new answers are welcome on questions with accepted answers. That is the furthest thing from the truth. If you happen across a question and you have something new or otherwise helpful to contribute, then you are strongly encouraged to post a new answer. It doesn't matter if the question is 20 years old, if you're a new user or an old hand, or if the question already has an accepted answer.

The only time you shouldn't answer a question is if your answer is going to duplicate information that is already available in the other answers. Nothing new under the sun, in other words. This is just clutter—upvote the other answer(s) instead.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that old questions shouldn't get new answers, that's of course a totally valid thing to do, and beneficial to the community when there is new or better solutions. What I was curious about was the specific case of reposting an already accepted answer as your own. In any case your answer provided the food for thought I was looking for and I'll accept it.

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty sure that was what you meant. Just wanted to be clear for others who might be reading this. If the answer has already been accepted, it's more likely to be useful and therefore garner upvotes.

Comment: worth noting that in the past, there was sort of _systemic force_ acting against piling on answers: asker and answerers were interested to keep it below CW threshold, otherwise they'd stop getting reputation. Now rep denial is (rightfully!) [gone](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228940/165773), but the side effect is, it took away that force. Nowadays, only few <strike>idiots</strike> idealists concerned about [meta-tag:answer-quality] would put their effort against it, everyone else is essentially rewarded by a system for doing nothing. _[meta-tag:bump]z bring repz_

Comment: ...FWIW [vast majority seems to believe this is not an issue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266175/839601 "see 'If “answer locks” shouldn't be used on comprehensively answered questions, then what should we do instead?'")

Comment: As a low-rep noobie who has done exactly this (constructively), I feel this is a good place to ask a follow-up question: how does one handle going about suggesting their answer is more faithful to the OP's original train of thought and intention, i.e: [this thread.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066503/javascript-iterating-over-array-with-non-consecutive-keys/37956589#37956589) Is there a flag or some protocol? I ask because I found that thread through google looking for a solution similar to what I eventually posted, and when I found that question nothing there was really helpful.

Comment: @WlkrShrpe Well, there really is no protocol. If you think you have a better answer, you just post it and let the community decide (by voting). If the person who originally asked the question is still around on the site, they might notice your answer and change which one they've marked as accepted (if yours is truly a better solution). But even if the person who originally asked the question is long gone, or doesn't like your answer better, your answer can still help other people who happen upon the question (like you, in this case!). So no, don't flag it; there's nothing a moderator could do.

Comment: I miss here the possibility that you can rephrase an answer to make it much more intelligible. This can especially be true for mathematical truth. Slight modifications of arguments can go a long way. This should not be discouraged. I can imagine that in the long run an established answer will be overtaken and the tick mark moved to the new answer.  So I answer if I've to contribute something, anything.

Answer (score -5):

As I do not hav 50 rep (yet) and therefore cannot comment, I'll post my contribution as answer.

I'd think that whenever this happens, it's mainly due to a lack of moderation. Once a question starts attracting low-quality answers - as in your example - it's usually closed by moderators (or at least require a minimum amount of rep to add another anser). A neat solution to this behaviour, IMHO.

However, I could imagine that things could be improved by letting the poster of a question (in addition to moderators) - once an answer has been accepted - set a minimum rep for further answers.

Comment: I disagree with your proposal, that would be a horrible idea IMHO. Some people would pro'ly start to request answers from 100k+ people only and the answer rate would drop.

Comment: _As I do not hav 50 rep (yet) and therefore cannot comment, I'll post my contribution as answer._ Don't do that. Never do that. This looks like an answer to me, in any case.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Yes, moderation (i.e., protecting and/or closing the question) can help to prevent this problem *once it starts occurring*. But you have to have people posting these garbage answers first before it attracts the attention of moderators. We don't want to proactively protect questions. That discourages people who have a useful answer from contributing it, which goes against the whole purpose of this site.