# Collection of answers that don't refer to the code in the question

Tags: discussion, support, answer-quality, popularity

While reviewing a first answer I also took a look at the corresponding
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5145951/2675154) including all other answers. The question appears to be about homework and it is not really good, but that is not my point.

Most answers don't refer to the code in the question, but present individual solutions to the original task of the OP. These answers seem to attract more of such answers (as [the one that I reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29372187/2675154)), resulting in a collection of qualitatively questionable homework solutions without explanation (apart from the comments given in the code).

Even trying to motivate the poster of the latest answer didn't do the trick to improve the situation.

I didn't face a similar situation before and therefore I don't know how to deal with it. Is there any action to take on this or is the situation fine as it is and I should care about more serious issues?

Also, the code of three answers contains author information (such as name, workplace, email). Is it an acceptable behavior to provide such kind of information in a post?

Comment: I'd guess that the author information is from their own personal past homeworks/projects while in school.  Then it was just a simple copy-paste (although I don't know why they left in the author info).  There's certainly nothing wrong with posting your own personal information.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Maybe there is nothing wrong with posting personal information, but is it really welcome? As far as I understood, you are no longer the owner of your code after posting it on Stack Overflow. Or did I get that wrong?

Comment: I think you're correct that any code posted on SO is public.  As far as it being welcome, I personally don't care about author's information one way or another.  Since the author information isn't distracting, it's ok.  It certainly doesn't improve the post any either though.

Comment: 16K views suggest that the question is somewhat popular (title looks good for googling). As such, it is doomed to attract garbage from passers by (see eg [1](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269421/839601 "example"), [2](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255527/839601 "example")), unless someone with sufficient privileges protects it. (_Melancholically_ I'm outta votes today but I guess I will loose about 5 repz tomorrow on some "answers" over there)

Comment: @honk You got that wrong.  You are most certainly the owner, you're simply giving everyone else in the world the right to share that content that you own, as well as to use it and create derived works from it, so long as you are cited as the owner of that content.

Comment: @gnat: Thank you for providing the links, I will dig through the posts.

Comment: @JonasCz The posts don't merit a VLQ flag.  Downvotes, sure, but VLQ, no.  VLQ is for content that isn't even an answer, not for answers that you just think are bad.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you for protecting the question concerned.

Comment: @ryanyuyu If they're a copy/paste student, there's a chance they didn't notice their information was still there.  I once had a student copy another student's homework, including the name of the original student...

Comment: @Izkata I'm guessing that student was subject to academic misconduct for being really dumb.  That's just sad.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I am not a lawyer, so don't trust me, but if I remember how creative commons works, *technically* whoever writes the code owns it. Its just that they agree that other people can use it for free. Thats just because of how stupid copyright works (if SO owned all the code, they could be evil, so it is better this way.) I do agree in the spirit of it everyone owns it.

Comment: @PyRulez neither am I a lawyer.  At any rate, the bottom line is still that the other users of the site are free to use any posted code.  Right?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I am not lawyer (I keep saying that because getting sued would suck), but I believe that is how it works. It would be like if we each bought a part of pennsylvania, but signed a contract saying anyone could farm on it. See the copyright notice at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @PyRulez cool.  That's what I figured.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Also, I'm not a farmer, but I think the Pennsylvania idea is a great idea. SO should start planning that.

Comment: @Servy, the answers have now been deleted, which is a lot more extreme than a VLQ flag. Huh?

Comment: @JonasCz Flagging as VLQ is to request deletion, so no, it's not *more* extreme, it's *as* extreme.

Comment: And here I was looking to find out if there was a collective noun described by the title of this question. A misguide of answers? A hassle of answers?

Comment: @pjmorse: I'm sorry, English isn't my mother tongue. Please feel free to edit the title and add a pinch of pep to it ;)

Comment: @honk ha! No, no, your title is fine, it's my mind going on tangents.

Comment: @pjmorse: My mind also does this from time to time: When writing the title I thought that somebody might get the impression that I'm trying to offer the best of worst answers exclusively here on meta at an unbeatable price ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> I don't know how to deal with it. Is there any action to take on this [...]?

Downvote them if they are bad. If you aren't comfortable spending reputation on this, you can try adding a comment like *"What does this add to existing answers?"*

[Furthermore](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/new-protected-question-status/),

> If you see a question that is attracting a lot of drive-by noise answers, please flag it for moderator attention. We’ll turn on protection.

But I should point out that

> Most answers don't refer to the code in the question, but present individual solutions to the original task of the OP.

This is not necessarily a problem in and of itself. If every answer just fixed the OP's 1 error the Q&A would be less useful to others. An answer that shows a better alternative to solve the same problem can be a good answer because it's useful to others.

That said, I do think the answers in the referenced Q&A are poor because they are just a code block.

---

> [...] or is the situation fine as it is and I should care about more serious issues?

My opinion is that it's not fine and it's a serious issue.

[image: 16380]

The referenced Q&A is not an isolated example.

My opinion is that questions with answers like this make us look like a code dump junk heap and the answers should be deleted. I do not know whether this is a popular opinion but I do know that I've had flags that requested for deletion cleanup declined.

My opinion is that deleting this type of answer is good because it cleans up the site and simultaneously users who have their answers deleted have the chance to learn without having their intro to the site be a downvote. Leaving it around may also reinforce the idea that we want stuff like this.

<sub>(Side-note: they've been deleted now by 20k users.)</sub>

I don't have the impression there is a clear consensus on whether to flag answers like this as VLQ. It's ambiguous but some people do it. (Some of the ambiguity arises in whether or not these judgments require knowledge of the programming topic. Also, the queue provides incomplete context.)

---

> Also, the code of three answers contains author information

They will get spam emails, that's all. Perhaps they naively hoped for attribution.

---

Some related discussions:

- [Cleaning up questions overrun with low quality answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252331/cleaning-up-questions-overrun-with-low-quality-answers)
- [Is it OK to flag exact duplicate answers as Very Low Quality?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266236/is-it-ok-to-flag-exact-duplicate-answers-as-very-low-quality)
- [Why do low-rep users post new answers to already answered & accepted questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269421/why-do-low-rep-users-post-new-answers-to-already-answered-accepted-questions)
- [Duplicate answer as late answer from new user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/171494/duplicate-answer-as-late-answer-from-new-user)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It very much reflects my opinion. However, according to a [recent discussion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285927/2675154), flagging the answers concerned as VLQ doesn't seem to be the desired action. Also, commenting or even downvoting wouldn't improve the situation unless other members did the same. Bringing this up here on meta did the trick (oops), but I guess I shouldn't do that for every single incident. Is it recommended to call
attention to such situations somewhere in chat? Or is this overkill?

Comment: *"flagging the answers concerned as VLQ doesn't seem to be the desired action"* I might flag some of these but it depends on the answer. YMMV. [Code-only isn't criteria enough for a flag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/2891664) on its own. I don't see a problem with asking for help in a chat as long as the resultant activity follows the guidelines. ([See answers here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266994/2891664).)

Comment: I would only flag a code-only answer when I'm sure that the code is of no use at all. So, I see it similar to @Servy in his answer on the first question that you linked. Regarding asking for help in a chat: I would rather ask people for their opinion than immediately trying to mobilize downvoters based on my personal opinion. Do you (or anybody else) know whether there is a chat room where people are interested in discussing such issues? Or should I try the language specific chat room that fits the code language?

Comment: [Tavern on the Meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta) has traditionally been the place for such discussion. There is also [The SO Tavern](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/5/the-so-tavern-free-snacks) (I assume because of the SO meta split) and perhaps rooms like [LQPHQ](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/773/low-quality-posts-hq) but they are less active. Language-specific, sure, but not all have an active chat.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback and the additional links. This is very helpful for me.